# aplay cant read from config .asoundrc

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, alsa

I want aplay to read from .arecordrc file but it fails.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay numnuts.wav 
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1667:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
aplay: main:722: audio open error: No such device
```

When i provide the hardware in command line it works

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay -D hw:0,0 numnuts.wav 
Playing WAVE 'numnuts.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 11025 Hz, Mono
```

my .asoundrc:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat .asoundrc
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm "mic"
  playback.pcm "speaker"
}
pcm.mic {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
  }
}
pcm.speaker {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:0:0"
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me what had to change in pcm. speaker

aplay -l output

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, it was a typo mistake:

in pcm.speaker

```
replace pcm "hw:0:0"
```

to

```
pcm "hw:0,0"
```